# Css behavior on different browsers

Tags: css, conditional-statements

I'm trying to fix something in css of my project but the behavior of that button is different on IE8. So this is the code:

```
.virtualS{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF734C, #FF0000);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF734C, #FF0000);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff704a 0%,#ff0201 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FF734C, endColorstr=#FF0000);
    border:1px solid #eaeaea;
    height:14px;
}
```

the problem is with `height:14px` because on Firefox, Chrome, Opera I should have 16px and on IE 14px. So what can I do in order to fix this? I don't want to use a different `.css` file with conditional comments only for this so what can I do in order to have properly the same height for that button on IE and Firefox.

Comment: What is the reason that you need 14px for IE8 and 16px for other browsers? Can you post some code that demonstrates where this difference comes from?

Comment: here is an example, if you will run on ie8 you will see the diferrences.  http://jsfiddle.net/8Bppz/3/

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want 14px you might need to set `line-height: 14px`

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not W3C compliant the are ['hacks'](http://ajaxian.com/archives/css-browser-hacks) you can use in your css to target specific browsers, the compliant way would be to use `<!-- [if IE x]> <link ... /> <![endif] -->` these 'special comments' are recognised by IE and it loads the appropriate style sheet

Comment: Yes but i don't want to use a different css file with <!-- [if IE x]> <link ... /> <![endif] --> conditiona comments only for this.  I was thinking something like *htme .virtualS{...} hack... but not working

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if IE is rendering in quirks mode, if it is, the sizing will be incorrect. But it can be fixed by correcting the HTML.